# How to pass store procedure dynamic parameters from asp.net to power bi using .net sdk

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, powerbi

I have created store procedure for get power bi report. Now, I want to pass store procedure parameter value from asp.net to power bi.

Here is my direct query.
Exec sp_GetPropertyReport @UserId,@CompanyId

Now, I want to pass @UserId from .net to powerBi this direct query.

Is that possible to pass parameters from .net to powerbi direct query dynamic parameters? If yes then how?

If any alternative solution for it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have updated my code for better understand